# Windows Universal App namespaces

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

When I create a blank win-universal-app project, I then try to create a custom control, but I always get the error:

> The name '' does not exist in the namespace ''

I have to transition a windows 8.1 app to windows 10 that uses several costum controls...Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an example of the custom control you are trying to add?

Comment: Sometimes this type of error disapears after solution rebuild. But I suppose that you tried to rebuild the solution. Otherwise we need to see an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebuild / clear and build project. This type of error will disappear if everything is correct.